# Help on Expected Value of a probability density function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

The Problem: Consider the family of distributions with density $f(x) = \frac{1}{2\theta} exp[-\frac{|x|}{\theta}] , x \in (-\infty, \infty)$. Compute $E(|x|)$.

The Attempt: I was going to examine the cases when x is positive and when x is negative. When $x>0$, then $E(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x \frac{1}{2\theta} exp[-\frac{x}{\theta}] dx$. I am actually having a hard time integrating this function. Can you guys give some hints on how to solve this problem. Please do not work on the problem completely.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have not integrate this before, you can try with integration by part - note that the derivative of an exponential function is itself again and this is a common technique. Once you finish this, you can inductively compute the other gamma integral, and directly use the result when you are familiar with that. You can look for the pdf of gamma distribution afterward.

Comment: I tried integration by parts and what I came up with is this: When $x>0$, $E(X) =\frac{1}{2\theta} (-x\theta exp[-\frac{x}{\theta} ] -\theta^{2} exp[\frac{-x}{\theta}])$, evaluated from$ x=0$ from $x = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|X| = X\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant0\}} -X\mathsf 1_{\{X<0\}}$, it follows that 
$$
\mathbb E[|X|] = \int_0^\infty xf(x)\ \mathsf dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 xf(-x)\ \mathsf dx.$$
Since $f$ is an even function $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$, the above simplifies to
\begin{align}
2\int_0^\infty xf(x)\ \mathsf dx
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac1{2\theta} x e^{-\frac x\theta}\ \mathsf dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac1\theta x e^{-\frac x\theta}\ \mathsf dx\\
&=\theta.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You start with a Laplace (or double exponential distribution) symmetric about $0$.  Taking the absolute value turns it into an exponential distribution

Taking the absolute value of a distribution symmetric about $0$ has the effect of doubling the density on the positive values, so your calculation should be

$$E\left[|X|\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty} x \frac{1}{\theta} \exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right) dx$$

Integration by parts with $u=x$ and $dv=\frac 1\theta \exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right) dx$ should then lead you to $$\left. -x\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right)  \right|_0^\infty + \int_{0}^{\infty}  \exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right) dx$$

$$=\left. -x\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right)  \right|_0^\infty -\left. {\theta} \exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right) \right|_0^\infty$$

which is (apart from the factor of $2$) is what you have in a comment.  This is $[0-0]-[0-\theta]=\theta$ as you might have predicted from an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\frac1\theta$